# C# FileStream StreamWriter another process exception

Tags: c#, datagridview, filestream, streamwriter, flush

I'm writing a CSV file from a `DataGridView`.
When I open the file during the process (while the task is writing to the file) I get an error because:

`The process cannot access the file 'xyz\filename.csv' because it is being used by another process.`

I've tried  manually calling the `Flush()` method on both `file` and `swOut` after each write but I still get the error.

I need to use `FileMode.Append` because after file is created I add n-rows. I've tried each of the different options for the `FileShare` enumeration, but nothing is working.

Where am I wrong?

My code:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(file);
    swOut.AutoFlush = true;
    if (table.Rows.Count == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }
            swOut.Write(table.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }
        swOut.WriteLine();
    }
    swOut.Write(category.Replace(",", " ") + "," + name.Replace(",", " ") + "," + address.Replace(",", " ") + "," + locality.Replace(",", " ") + "," + cap.Replace(",", " ") + "," + tel.Replace(",", " ") + "," + fax.Replace(",", " ") + "," + www.Replace(",", " ") + "," + email_results.Replace(",", " ") + "," + business_url.Replace(",", " ") + "," + map_query.Replace(",", " "));
    swOut.WriteLine();
    file.Close();
    if (stop == true) output_file = "";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, posted as answer instead of comment. Display messagebox just before the closing bracket. Does it show?

Comment: Also where is `output_file` declared. What are you trying to achieve by `if (stop == true) output_file = "";` where is `stop` declared and set?

Comment: stop is a public bool that become true when i click on a stop btn. but at this time is always false so it can't do nothing.

Comment: @Peuczyński yes, it show messagebox.

Answer (score 1):

Why `file.Close();` ?

it should be `swOut.Close();`

EDITED :

Or like this

```
'using (FileStream file = new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
using (StreamWriter swOut = new File.AppendText(output_file))
{
    'StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(file);
    swOut.AutoFlush = true;
    if (table.Rows.Count == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }
            swOut.Write(table.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }
        swOut.WriteLine();
    }
    swOut.Write(category.Replace(",", " ") + "," + name.Replace(",", " ") + "," + address.Replace(",", " ") + "," + locality.Replace(",", " ") + "," + cap.Replace(",", " ") + "," + tel.Replace(",", " ") + "," + fax.Replace(",", " ") + "," + www.Replace(",", " ") + "," + email_results.Replace(",", " ") + "," + business_url.Replace(",", " ") + "," + map_query.Replace(",", " "));
    swOut.WriteLine();
    swOut.Close();
    if (stop == true) output_file = "";
}
```

Comment: I just modified my code as in my last answer: problem was that i was opening and closing (so unlocking) file every time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all filestream using the document in your code are closed using

```
      Close();
```

Example :

```
    //Create the File
    FileStream FS = new FileStream("C:/Path to document",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
    //Call the Close Method to Close the file
    FS.Close();
```

Make sure all the filestreams are closed and you will no longer get this error

Comment: How can this be a solution? OP has already used `using`, so it will be automagically diposed. Isn't it?

Comment: I've already added swOut.Close(); and  file.Close(); but nothing changed

Comment: I'm not talking about this code, i'm saying the other filestream codes  using the file in his Project

Comment: @aquanat make sure all the filestreams in your entire project code are closed, i have encountered the same problem many times and that was always the cause

Comment: if you're using filestream only in this code then i guess i dont know the solution

Comment: @TijesunimiPreciousAmesinlola yes, i confirm that i'm using filestreams only in this code. as you say, it's very strange that it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here the solution.

Before i declared

```
public FileStream file;
```

in main class.

Then when it starts to add rows to datagridview, i initialize the filestream:

```
file = new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```

Then every time i add a row, i add a row also in csv with this code:

```
 StreamWriter swOut =  new StreamWriter(file);
                        swOut.AutoFlush = true;
                        if (table.Rows.Count == 2)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                            {
                                if (i > 0)
                                {
                                    swOut.Write(",");
                                }
                                swOut.Write(table.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                            }
                            swOut.WriteLine();
                        }
                        swOut.Write(category.Replace(",", " ") + "," + name.Replace(",", " ") + "," + address.Replace(",", " ") + "," + locality.Replace(",", " ") + "," + cap.Replace(",", " ") + "," + tel.Replace(",", " ") + "," + fax.Replace(",", " ") + "," + www.Replace(",", " ") + "," + email_results.Replace(",", " ") + "," + business_url.Replace(",", " ") + "," + map_query.Replace(",", " "));
                        swOut.WriteLine();
                        swOut.Close();
                        file.Close();
                        file = new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
                        //file.Lock(0, file.Length);
```

So FileStream is always open and it doesn't close every time as in my original code.

Thanks!